# url_for knowing only model symbol and an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Knowing these things

```
model_sym = :users
user_id = 1
```

I can do this:

```
url = "#{model_sym.to_s}/#{user_id}"
```

But is there a way I could do something like this?:

```
url = url_for(model_sym, user_id)
```

I could first "find" the user to pass into url_for, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Why not use rails helper to generate the routes. model_path(user_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use [`polymorphic_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html):

```
polymorphic_url([model_sym, user_id])
```

---

**Resources**

Having written that, it seems you're getting confused about the resourceful nature of Rails. 
Built on Ruby, Rails is *object-orientated*, which means that everything you do needs to be tied to an `object` (model):

[image]

The reason why this is important is because all of Rails' helpers etc are built around *objects*. That's why when you create a new set of routes, you can simply call `resources` (as *resourceful* is to give the object a set of attributes / methods you can call)

--

**Implementation**

The problem you have is you're not basing your routes around any objects - you're simply 
calling symbols / numbers. Although this will work, it's not the "right" way to create Rails functionality

Your ideal situation is to *build objects*, and pass them to the routing structure of your application. To build an object, you'd do the following:

```
@user = User.find params[:id] #-> builds object
<%= link_to "Users Path", @user %> #-> pulls route from object
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
url_for(:controller => model_sym.to_s, :action => :show, :id => user_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do `send("#{ model_sym.to_s.singularize }_path", id)` to get the URLs you want.
This would call `user_path(1)` in your example.

Comment: which is not a correct route - it should be `user_path(1)` if using typical resourceful routing.